# Java String.split() on numeric strings

Tags: java, string

I have a '|' delimited csv file with 2 columns:

```
A    |B
87657|5
87688|8
32134|4
...
```

I want to make a Map by reading this file, taking the column A values as string, and column B values as int.

I do (with delimiter = "|"):

```
    Map<String, Integer> output = new HashMap<>();
    assert delimiter.length() == 1;
    int count = 0;
    for(String line: Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(docidFreq), Charset.defaultCharset())) {
        count++;
        //skipping header row
        if (count == 1 ) {
            continue;
        }
        String tokens[] = line.split(delimiter);
        output.put(tokens[0], Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]));
    }
    return output;
```

However, the map contains single digit keys and values like (No relation to the sample file lines given above):

```
1:2
8:5
9:3
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should show us what `delimiter`is..

Comment: @RC Sorry, edited. The delimiter is the string "|".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use the symbol '|' you have to escape it with two '\' like below in split.

```
split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (line, "\\|");
map.put(st.nextToken(), Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
String line = "87657|5";//line from a file
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
String[] numbers = line.split("\\|");//assuming you have entries in file like "num1|num2"
map.put(numbers[0], Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]));
System.out.print(map);

Output:
{87657=5}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either any of following ways:

```
String[] str = line.split("\ \|");
```

or

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (line, "\ \|");
```

`split()` quite easy to use whereas `StringTokenizer` much faster than `String.split()` method.